# Why make the server push data?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, notifications, push-notification

Why make the server push data to get notifications, like using SingleR while it can be made client side?

Using a javascript timing event, that checks for recent updates at specified time intervals user can get notifications as long as he remains connected to the server.

So my question is why do more work at the server that the client can already do?

Comment: Why ping the server 10 times a minute just to see if there is an update... instead, make the server push only if new information is available.  Less work for either side.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're saying but going on you last question, Server as general a lot more powerful than a client computer so should get the job done quicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not more work to the server, it's less work. Suppose that you have 10000 clients (and the number could easily be in the 100K or even millions for popular web-sites) polling the server every X seconds to find out if there's new data available for them. The server would have to handle 10000 requests every X seconds even if there's no new data to return to the clients. That's huge overhead.

When the server pushes updates to the clients, the server knows when an update is available and it can send it to just the clients this data is relevant to. This reduces the network traffic significantly.

In addition it makes the client code much simpler, but I think the server is the critical concern here.

Answer (score 0):

First if you didn't use server push you will not get instant update for example you can't do chat application, second why bothering the client to do job that it is not designed to do it? third you will have performance issue on the client cause like @Ash said server is a lot more powerful than a client computer.